My loss is increasing instead of decreasing when i use a regularizer, but if i don't use regularizer then it stays at 00000e+00 or something
This is my model architecture:
activation = LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1)  # You can adjust the slope (alpha) as 

needed

# Text input
text_input_layer = Input(shape=(500,))
embedding_layer = Embedding(max_words, 50)(text_input_layer)
normalized_embedding = BatchNormalization()(embedding_layer)  # Add BatchNormalization layer
replace_zeros = Lambda(lambda x: tf.where(tf.equal(x, 0), 0.001 * tf.ones_like(x), x))(normalized_embedding)
replace_nan = Lambda(lambda x: tf.where(tf.math.is_nan(x), 0.001 * tf.ones_like(x), x))(replace_zeros)
text_layer = Conv1D(256, 3, activation=activation)(replace_nan)
text_layer = MaxPooling1D(3)(text_layer)
text_layer = Conv1D(256, 3, activation=activation)(text_layer)
text_layer = MaxPooling1D(3)(text_layer)
text_layer = Conv1D(256, 3, activation=activation)(text_layer)
text_layer = MaxPooling1D(3)(text_layer)
text_layer = Flatten()(text_layer)
text_layer = Dense(512, activation=activation)(text_layer)

# Image input
image_input_layer = Input(shape=(256, 256, 1))
replace_zeros_image = Lambda(lambda x: tf.where(tf.equal(x, 0), 0.001 * tf.ones_like(x), x))(image_input_layer)
replace_nan_image = Lambda(lambda x: tf.where(tf.math.is_nan(x), 0.001 * tf.ones_like(x), x))(replace_zeros_image)
image_layer = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation=activation)(replace_nan_image)
image_layer = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(image_layer)
image_layer = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation=activation)(image_layer)
image_layer = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(image_layer)
image_layer = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation=activation)(image_layer)
image_layer = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(image_layer)
image_layer = Flatten()(image_layer)
image_layer = Dense(512, activation=activation)(image_layer)

# Concatenate text and image branches
concatenated_layer = Concatenate()([text_layer, image_layer])
#kernel_regularizer=l1(0.001)
# Dense layers
dense_layer = Dense(512, activation=activation)(concatenated_layer)
dense_layer = Dense(1024, activation=activation, kernel_regularizer=l1(0.0000001))(dense_layer)
dense_layer = Dense(2048, activation=activation)(dense_layer)
output_layer = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense_layer)

# Define the model with two inputs
model = Model(inputs=[text_input_layer, image_input_layer], outputs=output_layer)
model.summary()

Here is my compiling section and then running it:
optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate=0.1, clipvalue=1.0)
loss_function = CategoricalCrossentropy()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss=loss_function,
              metrics=[CategoricalAccuracy()])

Am still new to two-input layer-type architecture
Also here is the shape of my data:
print("Text Data Shapes:")
print("Training:", x_train_text.shape, y_train_text.shape)
print("Validation:", x_val_text.shape, y_val_text.shape)
print("Test:", x_test_text.shape, y_test_text.shape)
​
print("\nImage Data Shapes:")
print("Training:", x_train_image.shape, y_train_image.shape)
print("Validation:", x_val_image.shape, y_val_image.shape)
print("Test:", x_test_image.shape, y_test_image.shape)
Text Data Shapes:
Training: (5000, 500) (5000,)
Validation: (2000, 500) (2000,)
Test: (1000, 500) (1000,)

Image Data Shapes:
Training: (5000, 256, 256) (5000,)
Validation: (2000, 256, 256) (2000,)
Test: (1000, 256, 256) (1000,)

Here the text data was tokenized, as such the shape is like that.
